# How to make ansible establish connections to host (connection-check)

Tags: ssh, ansible, virtual-machine

I am trying to set up remote VMs using ansible. For this, my inventory contains the host definitions, and my playbook contains the necessary steps.
It is my understanding that ansible checks all hosts defined in the inventory before running the playbook tasks, and aborts if one of the hosts is unreachable.

Now, the connection to the VMs need to be created first by opening SSH tunnels (or more precise: `az network bastion tunnel` tunnels). This is necessary to actually make access to the VMs possible via ssh. As a result, when I want to open the tunnels via ansible, this results in the connections being always unavailable by definition, and ansible wont run. This can be worked around by using `ignore_unreachable: true`.

After setting `ignore_unreachable` and adding `pre_tasks` which open those tunnels, my tasks run successfully.

The downside of this approach is that the summary will always report errors (albeit the overall tasks will complete successfully), and ansible works in a mode where it "thinks" that none of the hosts is actually available.

So the question is, is there a better solution to this? I hoped that `pre_tasks` were exempt from the connection-check, which unfortunately is not the case.

Thanks in advance!

ps: Please don't recommend opening the tunnels outside of ansible.